# Vuejs v-for display record how to sort the data by dsc or asc

Tags: sorting, vue.js, v-for

Vuejs v-for display record how to sort the data by dsc or asc.

v-for="thing in things" and I want to sort by the thing.price, 
how can I do this.. 
thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way to do that would be to use a computed property. Assuming `.price` is a number (not a string) and you want to preserve the original array, something like

```
computed: {
    sortedThings() {
        return this.things.slice().sort((a,b) => a.price - b.price);
    }
}
```

And then, in the template

```
<div v-for="thing in sortedThings" ...
```